# Adding array into datatable with limited columns

Tags: c#, arrays

I already know how to add array into `datatable`.

```
string[] months = {"Jan" , "Feb" , "Mar" , "Apr" , "Jun"};
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("M1");
dt.Columns.Add("M2");
dt.Columns.Add("M3");
dt.Columns.Add("M4");
dt.Columns.Add("M5");
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++)
{
   row[i] = months[i];       
}

dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

The above code perfectly works. But I have a **different** question. Lets assume I have an array of 8 values.

```
string[] arr = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};
```

Now I have created a new `datatable` with 4 columns.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("v1");
dt.Columns.Add("v2");
dt.Columns.Add("v3");
dt.Columns.Add("v4");

DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
```

Now I want to add the values of array in to columns like

```
arr[0] = v1
arr[1] = v2
arr[2] = v3
arr[3] = v4

arr[4] = v1
arr[5] = v2
arr[6] = v3
arr[7] = v4
```

**Update 1**

I have a function in which I want to perform all these actions

```
public string LoadAMIReadings(string startTS, string endTS, string batch, string divCode, string cc_code)
{

    totalRec = 0;
    processedRec = 0;
    this.BATCH = batch;
    this.DIVCODE = divCode;
    this.CCCODE = cc_code;
    this.FROMDATE = startTS;
    this.TODATE = endTS;
    HESservicesDoCommandRequest obj = new HESservicesDoCommandRequest();




DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Application_No", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("REF_NO", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("METER_SERIAL_NO", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("XMETER_NO", typeof(string));

// here I want to call the modified solution

int rowCount = bill.Length / dt.Columns.Count; // array bill is declared globally with 7780 values in it
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dt.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        // In case of 2 rows:

        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 0 = 0
        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 1 = 1
        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 2 = 2
        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 3 = 3

        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 0 = 4
        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 1 = 5
        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 2 = 6
        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 3 = 7

        row[columnIndex] = bill[(rowIndex * dt.Columns.Count) + columnIndex];
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}


if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    totalRec = dt.Rows.Count;
    string ReqEnvPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReadEnvPath"].ToString();
    XElement SoapReqEnv = XElement.Load(ReqEnvPath);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        string uniqueID = dr["APPLICATION_NO"].ToString();
        string meterNo = dr["METER_SERIAL_NO"].ToString();

        string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
        StringBuilder sbArg0 = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            sbArg0.AppendFormat(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>          " + SoapReqEnv.ToString(), uniqueID, startTS, endTS, timestamp, this.HEXURL, this.HEXUID, this.HEXPWD);
            Guid currentGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

            obj.getResponseAsync(sbArg0.ToString(), currentGuid + "$" + uniqueID);
            obj.getResponseCompleted += this.myHandler;
            string delayMS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DelayMS"].ToString();
            ushort delay = 1000;
            ushort.TryParse(delayMS, out delay);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error += "Error for UniqID:" + uniqueID + "Desc:" + ex.Message + "\n";
        }
        finally
        {
            //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
        }
    }
}

return error;
}
```

How can I add them?

Comment: `0 <= i%4 <= 3` does what you want

Comment: @dcg Can you please elaborate  a bit more ?

Comment: What I mean is that if `i` is your array index, then `i%4` will give you an index between `0` and `3` and you could use that to index your `row`

Comment: @dcg like this `for (int i = 0; i <=i%4; i++)` ?

Comment: No like this `for (int i=0; i< arr.Length; i++){row[i%4]=arr[i];}`, if you can index your row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Code example; this is not the best or shortest implemention, but it is a clear and understandable one for **novice** programmers.

```
string[] arr = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };

int rowCount = arr.Length / dt.Columns.Count;
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dt.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        // In case of 2 rows:

        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 0 = 0
        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 1 = 1
        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 2 = 2
        // row 1: (0 * 4) + 3 = 3

        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 0 = 4
        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 1 = 5
        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 2 = 6
        // row 2: (1 * 4) + 3 = 7

        row[columnIndex] = arr[(rowIndex * dt.Columns.Count) + columnIndex];
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

**Solution 2**

A more **advanced** and **edge-case-safe** **solution** which uses extension methods to split the original array to multiple sub-arrays and fill a datatable.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this T[] array, int size)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
        {
            yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
        }
    }

    public static void FillDataTable<T>(this DataTable dataTable, T[] input)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> rowValues = input.Split(dataTable.Columns.Count);
        foreach (IEnumerable<T> rowValue in rowValues)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

            T[] cellValues = rowValue.ToArray();
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < cellValues.Length; columnIndex++)
            {
                // 'Safe'-check in case the original array didn't contain enough values. The cell value will remain 'null'
                if (columnIndex < dataTable.Columns.Count)
                {
                    row[columnIndex] = cellValues[columnIndex];
                }
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("v1");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("v2");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("v3");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("v4");

        dataTable.FillDataTable(input);    
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moeez **Solution 2** will indeed work up to n-values in the orginal (in this case 'arr') array. If the sub-array doesn't contain enough values, the cell value of the row will remain empty. If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: @Ordai.. In actual I have array of 7780 values

Comment: @Moeez The number of values shouldn't matter. Are you going to add those values sequentially? (so the first row will get value 1,2,3,4 and the second one 5,6,7,8 as described in your  OP?) Solution 2 should not cause any issues.

Comment: @Ordai.. Yes That's what I want. Your solution 2 looks good for me but I have a function in which I am doing all these things. Can you please help me out that how can I call it in my function. I'll update my question aswell ?

Comment: @Moeez I've updated **Solution 2** which is a more generic implementation and is able to handle different kinds of input (not only string arrays, but integers as well).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190867/discussion-between-moeez-and-odrai).

Comment: @Moeez You're welcome, I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: can you please see my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410575/save-an-object-into-excel-file-in-c-sharp)?

Answer (score 1):

What I mean is that you can do something like this:

```
DataRow row = null;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0)
    {
        row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    row[i % 4] = arr[i];
}
```

**EDIT**: Take this as an example:

```
var arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 40).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0) { Console.WriteLine("new row"); }
    Console.WriteLine($"row[{i % 4}] = arr[{i}];");
}
```

The output would be:

```
new row
row[0] = arr[0];
row[1] = arr[1];
row[2] = arr[2];
row[3] = arr[3];
new row
row[0] = arr[4];
row[1] = arr[5];
row[2] = arr[6];
row[3] = arr[7];
new row
row[0] = arr[8];
row[1] = arr[9];
row[2] = arr[10];
row[3] = arr[11];
new row
row[0] = arr[12];
row[1] = arr[13];
row[2] = arr[14];
row[3] = arr[15];
...
```

Which is what you want, right?

Comment: It works only for 8 values bigger than that it gives `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Give me an example where that happens

Comment: I added 32 values and after the 8th I got the error

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want.

Comment: So where is that you're having `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, need to add hooks for the edge cases but the concept is simple enough.

```
        string[] arr = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("v1");
        dt.Columns.Add("v2");
        dt.Columns.Add("v3");
        dt.Columns.Add("v4");
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        int col = 0;
        foreach (var val in arr)
        {
            if (col > 3)
            {
                col = 0;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row[col] = val;
            }
            else
            {
                row[col] = val;
                col++;
            }
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
```